# Configuring an Activity window

Tags: android

The Configure Activity window no longer appears when creating a new activity in Android Studio (version 3.4.2). How do I easily change the name of MainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change name of any component (activity, fragment, variable etc) by doing this: ***Right click*** on name of component > **Refactor** > **Rename**. Or just by pressing shortcuts of this action. In my case only **Sift + F6**.